# How to add filter result to select menu

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm stuck with my first dashboard project with d3, dc and crossfilter. Cannot find a solution.

```
"ETCBTC","BUY","0.002325","1.04","0.00241800","0.00104","ETC"
"ETCBTC","SELL","0.002358","1.04","0.00245232","0.00000245","BTC"
"LTCETH","SELL","0.30239","0.006","0.00181434","0.00000181","ETH"
"LTCETH","SELL","0.30239","0.149","0.04505611","0.00004506","ETH"
```

I have different trading pairs in first column and from it i need to use only last pair BTC and ETH in this example.

I found the filter that helps me to do that.

The thing is I need to have BTC and ETH in my select menu which can apply filter.

```
function show_market_selector(ndx) {
    var marketDim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("Market"));
    var selectorMenu = marketDim.group();

    function filterItems(query) {
        return ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("Market")).filter(function(el) {
            return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > 0;

        });
    }
    filterItems("BTC");
    var select = dc.selectMenu("#market-selector")
                    .dimension(marketDim)
                    .group(selectorMenu);

    select.title(function (d){
        return "BTC";
    });

}
```

Now I get all pair in group in this menu. But my target is just to have BTC and ETH in the select menu.

I hope someone can give me advice. Thank you.

Comment: What's about `el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) === 3;` ?

Comment: its filtring well already. It's about how to put for exaple filterItems("BTC") and filterItems("ETH") inside dropdown menu as a BTC and ETH.

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag to ask questions about the charting library. [dc] is a classic unix calculator utility. (Fixed.)

Comment: Also, it's never helpful to use the [javascript] tag for dc.js/crossfilter questions - you'll get a lot of people talking about basic array functions and stuff. I removed that.

Comment: Thank you for advise. Next time i will do better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be easier just to use the currency as your dimension key:

```
var currencyDim = ndx.dimension(d => d.Market.slice(3)),
    currencyGroup = marketDim.group();
var select = dc.selectMenu("#market-selector")
                .dimension(currencyDim)
                .group(currencyGroup);
```

You don't really want to create a new dimension every time `filterItems` is called - dimensions are heavy-weight indices which are intended to be kept around.

The name of `dimension.filter()` is confusing - it's nothing like JavaScript's `Array.prototype.filter()`, which returns the matching rows. Instead, it's an imperative function which sets the current filter for that dimension (and changes what all the *other* dimensions see).

If you need a "from currency" dimension, that would be

```
var fromCurrencyDim = ndx.dimension(d => d.Market.slice(0,3))
```